# Return a value from an async event emmiter in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, eventemitter

I have an event emitter

```
@OnEvent(ANALYSIS_CREATED_EVENT, { async: true })
  async handleAnalysisCreatedEvent(event: AnalysisCreatedEvent) {
    this.logger.debug('Processing AnalysisCreatedEvent...');
    const { createAnalysisDto, analysisId, results, hash, analysisName, authContext, backtested } = event;

    const savedAnalysis = await this.analysesRepository.create({
      createdBy: authContext.by,
      updatedAs: authContext.as,
      updatedBy: authContext.by,
      ownerId: authContext.as,
    });

    const resultData = { id: analysisId, results, backtested };

return savedAnalysis.id
  }
```

I then call the eventEmitter in another file

```
const res = await this.eventEmitter.emitAsync(ANALYSIS_CREATED_EVENT, analysisCreatedEvent);
    console.log('the result from the event emitter is ************', res)
```

however the result I get is

```
the result from the event emitter is ************ [
  Immediate {
    _idleNext: null,
    _idlePrev: null,
    _onImmediate: [Function (anonymous)],
    _argv: undefined,
    _destroyed: false,
    [Symbol(refed)]: true,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 30080,
    [Symbol(triggerId)]: 29827,
    [Symbol(kResourceStore)]: Store { logger: [EventEmitter] }
  }
]
```

What am i doing wrong? When i remove the { async: true } I get the correct data, but i do not want to remove it as the function is async.
How can i solve this?

Comment: NodeJs's EventEmitter dos not have an `emitAsync`. What library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the nestjs EventEmitter

Comment: There's not a way to get the returned value from the emitted function. That's not generally how emitted functions work. If you want to get that value, you could call the function directly instead so you _could_ get the return.

Comment: How do you mean?